# Video embedding CSS width not consistant

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog where my featured images & videos extend outside of the post, but I've run into a problem.

Whenever I'm embedding videos outside of YouTube, the embedding messes up completely. And I'm not sure why.

I have two examples here, please check the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQwp4.jpg

The css line that controls the width is .fluid-width-video-wrapper, and the code is:

```
width: 113% !important;
height: 51px;
margin-left: -6.4%;
```

**Live demo here:**
Correct article: https://www.droppet.se/visuellt/en-man-uppfostrar-en-ekorre/
Incorrect article: https://www.droppet.se/sport/cavani-och-mbappe-kombinerade-till-ett-drommal/ (password wvideo)

Comment: The width is SUPPOSED to be 113%, not 100%. As I said, it's supposed to extend outside of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Change the width: 113% to 100% and get rid of margin-left

```
.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
    /* margin-left: -6.4%; */
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Comment: No, it is supposed to be wider than the container.

Answer (score 0):

Your container *is* the desired size.

The problem is inside the iframe; the div `.media-container` has these CSS rules, which prevent the video from being the full width of the framed document:

```
height: 56.23vw;
max-width: 177.85vh;
```

Removing the `max-width` rule from that class corrects the problem.

But since you're framing a third-party site, you won't be able to remove that class; instead you'd need to tweak the height of the iframe so that the framed site's rules match your layout.  Changing your `.fluid-width-video-wrapper` height to any height larger than `85px` seems to do it.  (May not be the ideal way to fix this, though; I haven't looked closely enough at the rest of your code to understand why that height rule exists.)